# Angular 5 Page Jumping For Loop

Tags: javascript, html, angular

- Angular 5 - Chrome.

Am looking for suggestions to stop page jumping. I have a table  hooked up to an `ngFor` loop. If I am at the top of my page and perform an action which adds an element to the array, if that table with the `ngFor` loop is off the screen at the time (further down but out of view), the page literally jumps to that table to show me the added element. This is obviously very annoying for the end users and am wondering how to stop this from happening.

I only have noticed this for tables that do not have a max height and `overflow-y: auto`. You may say well make the table have a max height and overflow. This is fine until I have nested tables and then the scrolling is annoying on its own. Trying to get away from that solution.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] of this issue?  This doesn't sound like a normal behavior.

Comment: please share your code. i think you are making some mistake. you may have some autofocus in table or something

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug.  I believe it has to do with angular 5.

In my app.ts page, I was using a function to get the view height as well as navbar height.

```
getViewHeight() {

    let res = this.windowSizeHeight - this.el_navBarMain.nativeElement.clientHeight - 20;

    if (this.status) {
        res -= 40;
    }

    if (!this.isConnected()) {
        res -= 40;
    }

    return res;
}
```

In my html I was doing this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="overflow-y: scroll;" [style.height.px]="getViewHeight()">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

This function is what is causing this error.  So what I did was made variables instead and did it this way:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="overflow-y: scroll;" [style.height.px]="windowSizeHeight - navbarMainHeight - statusHeight - connectedHeight - 20">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Now the page does not jump.  Why in the world would a function doing the same exact thing cause it to jump but using variables does not?  I console logged the res variable from getViewHeight() and it doesn't change or flicker to 0 or anything like that.  Weird stuff.